# GDALWARP and OGR2OGR / CS2CS not agreeing on transformation?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, proj, gdalwarp

I am trying to transform some data (both raster and vector) from WGS84 to a Croatian Coordinate system defined by:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=5500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=550.499,164.116,475.142,5.80967,2.07902,-11.62386,0.99999445824 +units=m +no_defs
```

This works great in CS2CS (Rel 4.8.0):

```
cs2cs +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=5500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=550.499,164.116,475.142,5.80967,2.07902,-11.62386,0.99999445824 +units=m +no_defs -r
```

And also great in OGR2OGR (version 1.9.2):

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=5500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=550.499,164.116,475.142,5.80967,2.07902,-11.62386,0.99999445824 +units=m +no_defs" out.shp  in.shp
```

But in GDALWARP (version 1.9.2), the data comes out c.400m offset to the West (I think it's possibly a rotation error based upon it's appearance):

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=5500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=550.499,164.116,475.142,5.80967,2.07902,-11.62386,0.99999445824 +units=m +no_defs" in.tif out.tif
```

An example of this can be seen below, where I digitised a vector layer around existing raster data, transformed both using the above commands, and then loaded into QGIS:

[image: example of offset error]

I can't for the life of me figure out why this could be - it is worthy of note that I have tried this with multiple Raster datasets from a variety of sources, and they always seem to be offset to the West by the same amount.

I have tried upgrading to GDAL 1.10.1, and this has no effect upon the output.

Has anyone ever seen this before and have any idea why it could be?

Comment: PROJ.4 and GDAL version?

Comment: I'd guess at maybe a precision issue with the SRS parameters.

Comment: Apologies, I've added versions into the question, it's GDAL/OGR 9.1.2, and Proj is Rel 4.8.0

Comment: I have tested against GDAL 1.10.1 and can confirm that the version is not the issue.

Comment: IIRC, the last parameter in +towgs84 is in parts per million, so I think it should be -5.54176 per [PROJ4 documentation](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms#towgs84-DatumtransformationtoWGS84).

Comment: @mkennedy, thanks for the input, but I'm afraid that that made no difference (which I think might be odd in itself?). How did you arrive at that value out of interest? Thanks again!

Comment: @jonnyhuck if x is the ppm value, the actual equations use 1 + x/1000000 to calculate the scale factor.

Comment: @mkennedy OK, so what value for x did you have for -5.4176? (forgive my ignorance, I'm just trying to see where the number came from) I guess it's not a number from my proj string?

Comment: @jonnyhuck I certainly may have calculated it wrong! 0.99999445824 = 1 + x/1000000, x = -5.54176

Comment: Ah, I see - apologies, I misunderstood how that worked! Thank you for explaining - greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After loading the files to QGIS, check the layers with `Rightclick -> Set CRS for layer`.

Sometimes QGIS guesses a similar existing EPSG code when you do not want it.

Testing on QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa, it thinks that EPSG:31275 is ment, with proj string:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=5500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs
```

which is alomst the same, except for the +towgs84 values.

So, nothing wrong with Gdalwarp ;-)

Comment: A cracking idea, but I'm afraid not - it's using the resulting "user generated" CRS. To be sure I created a new CRS using the PROJ string, and set both layers and the project to that, but I'm afraid it made no difference. Thanks for the suggestion though!